# How to solve the following error in jQuery ajax while using datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Trying to display json data from PHP into a jQuery datatable, I get an error.

This is my code:

```
function fetchProjectTable()
{
     $.ajax({
         url: Domain+"/include/process.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: { getProjectResult: 1 },
         success : function(data) 
         {
              //var o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
              //var o = JSON.parse(data);
              $('#project_table').dataTable({
                  data : data,
                  columns: [
                     {"data" : "id"},
                     {"data" : "p_name"},            
                     {"data" : "p_amount"}            
                  ],
              });
        
        //console.log(o);
        /*alert(o);
        console.log(o);*/
    }       
});
```

Comment: please some help to solve the problem in the code

Comment: WHAT is the error exactly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask